# Herança com Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework, design-pattern, herança

Estou estudando e tentando implementar o **Repository Pattern** em **C#** porém estou tendo algumas dificuldades em resolver certos problemas com a herança entre minhas classes do **Repository**, por exemplo a herança entre `Pessoa`, `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`, onde criei 3 classes, `PessoaRepository`, `PessoaFisicaRepository`, `PessoaJuridicaRepository`, onde `PessoaFisicaRepository` e `PessoaJuridicaRepository` estão herdando de `PessoaRepository`. 
O meu problema é que a classe `PessoaRepository` está permitindo incluir uma *PessoaJuridica* ou *PessoaFisica*, porém suas respectivas classes `Respository` teriam regras de negócio específicas, então a classe `PessoaRepository`, não poderia incluir suas derivadas, lembrando que também estou tentando seguir alguns conceitos de SOLID.

Minhas classes:
Modelo

```
[Table("Pessoa")]
public class PessoaEntity: IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(14)]
    public string CpfCnpj { get; set; }
}

[Table("PessoaFisica")]
public class PessoaFisicaEntity : PessoaEntity, IEntity
{
    public string NumeroRg { get; set; }
    public Sexo Sexo { get; set; }
}

[Table("PessoaJuridica")]
public class PessoaJuridicaEntity : PessoaEntity
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string NomaFantasia { get; set; }
}

public enum Sexo
{
    Masculino = 1,
    Feminino = 2
}

public class PessoaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PessoaEntity> Pessoa { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PessoaFisicaEntity> PessoaFisica { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PessoaJuridicaEntity> PessoaJuridica { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Meu Repository:

```
    public class Repository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    protected TContext _context;

    public Repository()
    {
        _context = new TContext();
    }

    public virtual TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(keyValues);
    }

    public virtual void InsertOrUpdate(TEntity obj)
    {
        var entity = Find(GetKeyValue(obj));
        if (entity == null)
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj);
        else
        {
            entity = obj;
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(Find(keyValues));
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }


    private object[] GetKeyValue<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
        var keysProperties = properties.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), true).Length != 0);

        List<object> retorno = new List<object>();

        foreach (var key in keysProperties)
        {
            retorno.Add(key.GetValue(entity, null));
        }

        return retorno.ToArray();
    }

}

public class PessoaRepository<TPessoa> : Repository<TPessoa, PessoaContext>
    where TPessoa : PessoaEntity, IEntity
{
    public override void InsertOrUpdate(TPessoa obj)
    {
        if (ConsisteInsertOrUpdate(obj))
        {
            base.InsertOrUpdate(obj);
        }
    }

    private bool ConsisteInsertOrUpdate(PessoaEntity obj)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.CpfCnpj))
        {
            var cpfCnpjDuplicados = _context.Pessoa.Where(a => a.CpfCnpj == obj.CpfCnpj && obj.PessoaId != a.PessoaId).Count();

            return cpfCnpjDuplicados == 0;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public class PessoaFisicaRespository<TPessoaFisica> : PessoaRepository<TPessoaFisica>
    where TPessoaFisica: PessoaFisicaEntity, IEntity
{
    public override void InsertOrUpdate(TPessoaFisica obj)
    {
        if (ConsisteInsertOrUpdate(obj))
        {
            base.InsertOrUpdate(obj);
        }
    }

    private bool ConsisteInsertOrUpdate(PessoaFisicaEntity obj)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj.NumeroRg))
        {
            var numeroRgDuplicados = _context.PessoaFisica.Where(a => a.NumeroRg == obj.NumeroRg && obj.PessoaId != a.PessoaId).Count();

            return numeroRgDuplicados == 0;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pablo, você pretende salvar isso num banco de dados? Não conheço muito este pattern, mas olhando para a forma como as entidades foram criadas, me parece estar um tanto estranho.

Do jeito que está sendo feito, você terá tabelas do tipo `Pessoa`, e também tabelas `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica` com os mesmos campos que `Pessoa`.

Não seria o caso de ter as 3 entidade e, invés de herança, usar um objeto do tipo `Pessoa` dentro das classes de `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`? Ficaria algo como:

```
[Table("Pessoa")]
public class PessoaEntity: IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(14)]
    public string CpfCnpj { get; set; }
}

[Table("PessoaFisica")]
public class PessoaFisicaEntity : IEntity
{
    public string NumeroRg { get; set; }
    public Sexo Sexo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Pessoa"), Required, Key]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public virtual PessoaEntity Pessoa { get; set; }
}

[Table("PessoaJuridica")]
public class PessoaJuridicaEntity : IEntity
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string NomaFantasia { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Pessoa"), Required, Key]
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public virtual PessoaEntity Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: eu vejo bem mais como herança, pois pessoa física é uma pessoa, mesma coisa para pessoa jurídica, sempre usei como herança até pq futuramente surge outros tipos de pessoas, como fornecedor, funcionário....

Comment: Mas vou refletir sobre sua proposta e ver se não fica melhor desfazer mesmo essa herança.

Comment: Sim, você tem razão de um ponto de vista de orientação a objetos. Mas se tratando de normalização de dados, as especializações acabam entrando em tabelas diferentes. Imagine fazer um relatório com as pessoas de diferentes entidades. Você precisará fazer vários `UNION ALL` das diferentes entidades. Você também terá `PessoaID` iguais para diferentes entidades (Pessoa Jurídica = 1 é uma coisa e Pesso Física = 1 é outra coisa). Para fazer isso funcionar legal, precisa declarar um objeto do tipo Sequence.

Comment: Eu acredito que deve existir uma maneira de fazer com que seus objetos se tornem uma herança e, ao mesmo tempo, salvar em entidades diferente. Mas não consigo te ajudar nesse sentido. Já desta maneira proposta acredito que fica bem simples pensar em entidades separadas. Espero que isso ajude!

Comment: hoje eu tenho 3 tabelas no banco, Pessoa, PessoaFisica e PessoaJuridica, quando quero fazer um relatório com base nas pessoas do sistema, busco tudo na entidade Pessoa. Não preciso fazer UNION ALL para pegar todas as pessoas do sistema e usando a herança, não acontece de uma Pessoa ser Fisica e Juridica.

Comment: Uma alternativa que fiz, foi transformar a classe `PessoaRepository` em `abstract`, impedindo assim que seja criada uma instância dessa classe, para novos tipos de pessoa, como por exemplo, Cliente, Transportadora e afins, que podem tanto ser Jurídica, como Física, eu não estou mais fazendo herança e sim declarando uma propriedade de Pessoa, sendo essa minha entidade abstrata também.

Comment: Vou postar minha solução em breve.

Comment: @rodrigogq, isto se chama TPC (Table per Concrete Type), onde no banco temos duas tabelas (PJ e PF) e três entidades (Pessoa, PJ e PF), caso queira ler mais a respeito: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Comment: @TobiasMesquita sei que esta resposta está antiga já, mas muito obrigado por ensinar como fazer isso no EF. Mais uma vez gostaria de comentar que ainda prefiro usar 3 tabelas diferentes. Isso já nos poupou muito esforço em diversas consultorias com diferentes clientes, além de salvar muito espaço em banco.