# Implementando o conceito de herança em banco de dados

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework, herança

Por quê o atributo `PessoaJuridicaId` não é gerado?

[image: Modelo no banco de dados]

Essa é a classe base `Pessoa`:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public Pessoa()
    {
        DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}
```

Essa é a classe `PessoaJuridica` que herda da classe `Pessoa`:

```
public class PessoaJuridica: Pessoa
{
    public int PessoaJuridicaId { get; set; }
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public string NomeComercial { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string IE { get; set; }
    public string IM { get; set; }
    public string CCM { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataAbertura { get; set; }
}
```

Esta é a classe Repositório:

```
public void Salvar(PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica)
{
    _repositorio.PessoaJuridica.Add(pessoaJuridica);
    _repositorio.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Como assim "não é gerado"? A segunda coluna da segunda tabela  tem nome **PessoaJuridicaId**.

Comment: Essa é minha dúvida, no meu entender essa coluna PessoaJuridicaId deveria ser atribuido um valor auto-incremento e não foi gerado valor nenhum, por quê ? Estou conceituando errado ? Essa coluna PessoaJuridicaId não deve existir ?

Comment: Porque a chave primária é `PessoaId` e não `PessoaJuridicaId`. Você pode usar uma chave composta se achar necessário. Particularmente, eu acho errado usar herança pra fazer isso no EF.

Comment: E como tornar `PessoaJuridicaId` **primária** ? Uma vez que a classe **base** é `Pessoa` e `PessoaId` é a chave dessa classe ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ia só comentar, mas ficou longo e acho que no fundo o erro é conceitual.

Onde está escrito que deveria ser autoincrementado? Qual o critério para gerar um identificador autoincrementado? Isto não ocorrerá sozinho. Sozinho o Entity Framework só consegue fazer com o primeiro campo, no caso ele fez com `PessoaID` que é o primeiro já herdado. Na verdade, ele fez certo, se quer herança mesmo.

Eu acho estranho ter identificadores diferentes nas duas tabelas e ter uma relação de herança. Isto só ocorre quando há algum tipo de [composição, associação ou agregação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101), não de herança. Se é herança então pessoa jurídica é o mesmo que pessoa, elas não existem separadamente, por que eles deveriam ter identificadores diferentes? Eu acho que o EF fez certo, o seu modelo que está adicionando algo desnecessário: `PessoaJuridicaId`.

Em geral eu prefiro fazer, no máximo, uma herança lógica, mas concretamente ter apenas as tabelas dos subtipos com os dados replicados, que é o que acontece concretamente na memória quando usamos herança em uma linguagem, o objeto é único, não existem dois da classe base e da derivada.

Pra falar a verdade esse modelo de ter fisicamente uma tabela base e suas derivadas separadas gera uma composição e não uma herança de fato. Herança é algo lógico para reusar código, não é para reusar dados. Em geral ter essa composição de tabelas não traz benefício algum e traz até malefícios, então não tem porque usar. Claro que pode ter algum caso que pode valer a pena. Mas precisa conceituar certo, entender todas as implicações. Não pode fazer por fazer, fazer porque "funcionou", tem que fazer o certo.

Não sou muito fã de herança em banco de dados porque quase todo mundo faz errado. Eu mesmo não sei se sei fazer certo, mas sei que a maioria faz errado :) Orientação a objeto já é complicado demais na memória e as pessoas acham que não, em banco de dados mais ainda. Sabe a estória de que morre afogado aquela pessoa que acha que sabe nadar. Quem não sabe nadar não morre porque não tenta. Quem sabe nadar mesmo não morre porque sabe. O problema é quando [a pessoa acha que sabe nadar e não sabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Tem algumas perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Herança correta no Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57288/101)
- [Herança no Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131009/101)
- [Herança X Composição - MySQL C# Entity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117567/101)
- [EF com herança TPT e campos de auditoria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113731/101)
- [Como configurar Mapeamento Entity Framework 1:N usando herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183816/101)
- [EF 6, Mapeamento com Fluent Api em classes com herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9793/101)
- [Herança com Repository Pattern](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42765/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Achei esse ponto do seu comentário esclarecedor: _"...esse modelo de ter fisicamente uma tabela base e suas derivadas separadas gera uma associação e não um herança de fato"_  vou rever como fazer essa implementação e repensar o ponto onde diz: _"Em geral eu prefiro fazer, no máximo, uma herança lógica"_.